# es posible agregar texto a mi archivo html que se agrege desde la misma pagina web

Tags: javascript, html, html5

me disculpo por la grafica no soy muy bueno maquetando
la idea es agregar al mismo documento html lo que estoy
enviando desde la web sin necesidad de base de datos, ejemplo
es algo asi como reescribir el archivo.

para que si cierro el navegador cuando vuelva a abrir el archivo me
mantenga lo que agrege.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
let texto = document.getElementById("texto");
// la idea es agregar al mismo documento html lo que estoy enviando
// sin necesidad de base de datos
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        #agregados{border:1px solid gray;}
        textarea{max-height: 100px; max-width: 300px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="agregados">
            <p>agregado desde la web</p>
        </div>
        <br><hr><br>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <textarea name="texto" id="texto" cols="30" rows="10">
            </textarea>
        </div>

        <button id="agregar">Agregar</button>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? Es mejor que pongas el texto del código, incluso puedes crear un fragmento de código donde se pueda hacer prueba del mismo y verificar errores.

Comment: pues la idea en si es saber si se puede agregar codigo al html que se guarde pero que no necesite de una base de datos, es decir como que se reescriba desde la web

Comment: Puede que sí, pero explica con claridad porque no se entiende. ¿Qué quieres decir con que *se reescriba desde la web*? Podriamos estar hablando de contenido dinámico, o de algo como LocalStorage u otra cosa. Explica con claridad, pon lo que has intentado (en código) y di qué problemas o errores tienes.

Comment: ¿Quieres que ese nuevo contenido se muestre solo para ti o para cualquier usuario que visite la página?

Comment: @Triby solo para mi ya que solo yo tendre acceso, en la respuesta de mas abajo Cristian mensiono algo de localStorage pero no quiero que la informacion se guarde en las cookies de la pagina, si no que se agregen al archivo que se esta ejecutando o si es necesario en un archivo el cual se reescriba localmente y que de ahi lea los datos repito solo si no hay posibilidad de agregar directamente el codigo al archivo que se esta mostrando.

Comment: Si no quieres que se guarde en el navegador, entonces necesitas hacerlo en el servidor, con el lenguaje que domines (PHP, Python, Node, etc.)

Comment: Vale @Triby o sea que si o si necesito una base de datos o una api

Comment: Sí, cualquier solución del lado del servidor, CMS, API, etc. y puede involucrar o no una base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Si que puedes, usando Javascript puedes agregar elementos o contenido a la página. Pero ten en cuenta que esos elementos solo van a estar visibles para el visitante que esté interactuando con la página. No va a guardarse en el servidor, no va a modificar realmente la página original.
Por ejemplo si tienes un bloque div con id="card"

```
obj = document.getElementById('card');
obj.innerText = "agregado desde la web";
```

También podrías usar un programa de servidor (en PHP o Nodejs) para recrear la página con nuevo contenido. Esto es algo más complejo, necesitas leer archivos y escribir archivos, si usas bas de datos pues interactuar con tablas... No es tan simple.

Comment: podrías combinarlo con el localStorage para que los cambios se mantengan mientras el navegador este abierto

Comment: Claro, o cookies, depende ya del caso particular, pero si se es un camino.

Comment: pues la verdad lo que quiero es lo que mencionaste en la respuesta que me escriba sobre el documento realmente @Juan.

Comment: @Christian con [LocalStorage](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.is-writable.php) los datos persisten aun cuando el navegador se cierra, en cambio SessionStorage sí destruye los datos cuando se cierra el navegador.

Comment: @Christian con LocalStorage los datos persisten aun cuando el navegador se cierra, en cambio SessionStorage sí destruye los datos cuando se cierra el navegador. [Ver la diferencia entre ambos aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API).

Comment: @A.Cedano Wow gracias, ahora entiendo por que mi app no funcionaba >_<. Indirectamente me has ayudado, gracias.

Comment: Cabe resaltar @A.Cedano que los datos no se guardan si estas como incognito independientemente de que navegador use, les agradezco la colaboracion aprendi varias cosas nuevas y decidi hacerlo con localStorage :)
lo que si es que no se si al borrar los archivos temporales se eliminan estos datos.

Comment: El borrado de lo que tengas en LocalStorage depende de varios factores como el tipo de navegador, el tipo de dispositivo o las acciones directas que realices para ello. Por ejemplo, en dispositivos móviles estos archivos podrían borrarse de forma automática si se necesitara espacio libre en el dspositivo. [En esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8537112/5587982) hay varias respuestas y enlaces que pueden ayudarte a profundizar sobre el tema.